# How to fix 'require_once() failed to open stream'

Tags: php, html

I'm making a website and I have to access the init file which is in the core folder. I'm currently in the includes folder `detailsmodal.php` file which is being triggered by an onclick event. The path I used

```
require_once './core/init.php';
```

is giving errors when i click on the modal:

> Warning: require_once(./core/init.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\mednew\includes\detailsmodal.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required './core/init.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\mednew\includes\detailsmodal.php on line 2

https://gyazo.com/e17324da3caa48c342255bb4bfd1344d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require_once('../../core/init.php');
```

I think you got two directories ahead instead of one.

Comment: It's giving me the same error when i try that. And no it isn't two directories outside. :(

Comment: Oh wait! You helped me! The right path is: '../core/init.php'. Thank you!

Comment: if it helps you, you can select this as answer